# Django application not visible

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy a Django application for the first time using `mod_wsgi` with `Apache` on a `Ubuntu 12.04` VM. I have been following several tutorials, especially [Ayman Farhat blog](http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/), this [excellent YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBMVVruB9Vs) and of course the official Django Documentation

This follows an [earlier question I posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874951/uploading-python-application-for-the-first-time-urlconfig-urls-not-working) wondering why my Django survey did not simply work when I uploaded it to the /var/www/ (blush!) I have since been looking into `mod_wsgi` as per the answers.

I'm not sure what stage I am missing. The project is able to start on the server via `python manage.py runserver` with no errors. I have also ran `python manage.py collectstatic` with no errors.

I then restart Apache with

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

However when I go the URL http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/surveythree/ where I expect to see the survey nothing is there. I just see the standard 404 error.

I am really not sure what I have to do next or why this is not working.

Below is my setup and what I have tried so far.

NOTE: I have a Bias_Experiment Django Project created in Pydev. It has three applications contained within an `src` folder.

- survey (my working project)
- polls (a tutorial i was following)
- bias_experiment (the root application with my settings file etc)

**My Project Structure**

[image]

**My virtual host** located at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/bias_experiment`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@email.com
ServerName kdeg-vm-18.scss.tcd.ie
ServerAlias http://collegeserver.ie/bias_experiment
WSGIScriptAlias / var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgi

Alias /static/ /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/static/
<Location "/static/">
    Options -Indexes
</Location >
</VirtualHost >
```

**My WSGI file** located at `/var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgi`

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('~/var/www/bias_experiment/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/var/www/bias_experiment')
sys.path.append('/var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment.settings'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("~/var/www/bias_experiment/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**My URL patterns** from `bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),        
    url(r'^surveythree/$', SurveyWizard.as_view([SurveyForm1, SurveyForm2, SurveyForm3, SurveyForm4, SurveyForm5])),   
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address you are going to in your browser does not match either the ServerName or ServerAlias directives in your Apache configuration, so the virtualhost won't know to respond to that request.

Note that ServerAlias should be similar to ServerName - a hostname, not a URL, without http prefix or path. Also note you can have multiple values for ServerAlias if you need that virtualhost to respond to many hostnames.

If you want the Django app to be served underneath /bias_experiment, that should be part of the WSGIScriptAlias.

So it should be:

```
ServerAlias phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie
WSGIScriptAlias /bias_experiment /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgi
```

Also I'm confused about the locations of your code. Is it in /var/www/... or /home/whoever/var/www? Your wsgi file refers to the latter, but the Apache conf has the former.

Next, virtualenv is supposed to take care of setting all the Python paths. So since you are running the activate script, you can remove the lines that modify sys.path and site.addsitedir. Although you might need to keep the one that adds the `src` directory.

Another problem is with your DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. It should be a Python module, not a file path - actually what you have is a cross between them both. Since `src` is on the Python path, you can just set this to 'bias_experiment.settings'.

Comment: Thanks for the help ;-) I did not know that the address I should visit should match either the Server Name or Alias, I will try variations of them once I make the other changes.

Comment: I have updated ServerAlias and the WSGIScriptAlias as per your instruction. My code is at `/var/www/` not `~/var/www/ I have changed this as well. I have also made the other changes.

Comment: With these changes made I am still not seeing the desired results. I am hosting on a private VM which has been made public though  http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment. This confusion i believe is at the root of the problem. I think its best to post another question focusing on that now that these other issues have been fixed?

Comment: I will make this as correct as it answered multiple issues and post a different question. Thanks for the help