# What should be the URL of my Django Application

Tags: python, django, apache, python-2.7

I have uploaded my first Django Application called **survey** (Its a work in progress) using `mod_wsgi` with `Apache` on an `Ubuntu` VM but I don't know what the URL of it should be. My VM has been made public through a proxyPass at http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment.

When working on my application locally I simply go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/surveythree/` Based on my urls.py (below) I thought that I would simply have to go to http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/surveythree/ to see my Survey application online. However I cant seem to find it...

My question: **What URL should I be using to locate my Survey Application based on my below settings?** Or have I missed some other step in the process?

The project has been uploaded, I have restarted the server, I have set it running with `python manage.py runserver`

Some of the urls I have tried

- http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/surveythree/
- http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/src/surveythree/
- http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/surveythree/

Below is my setup and what I have tried so far.

NOTE: I have a Bias_Experiment Django Project created in Pydev. It has three applications contained within an src folder.

- survey (my working project)
- polls (a tutorial i was following)
- bias_experiment (the root application with my settings file etc)

**My URL patterns** from bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),        
    url(r'^surveythree/$', SurveyWizard.as_view([SurveyForm1, SurveyForm2, SurveyForm3, SurveyForm4, SurveyForm5])),   
)
```

**My virtual host** located at /etc/apache2/sites-available/bias_experiment

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
ServerName phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment
ServerAlias phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie
WSGIScriptAlias /bias_experiment /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgi

Alias /static/ /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/static/
<Location "/static/">
    Options -Indexes
</Location >
</VirtualHost >
```

**My WSGI file** located at /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgi

```
import os
import sys
import site

# This is to add the src folder
sys.path.append('/var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'bias_experiment.settings'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("/var/www/bias_experiment/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**This is the project structure**

[image]

I had a [previous question related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188604/django-application-not-visable) which had multiple issues pointed out to me which I have since fixed so I am re-posting this here. I have been following several tutorials as details in that question.

Any help with this would be massively appreciated.

Thanks Deepend

EDIT: My Apache Error Log: `tail /var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
(bias_experiment)spillab@kdeg-vm-18:/var/www/bias_experiment/src$ sudo su
root@kdeg-vm-18:/var/www/bias_experiment/src# tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Fri Jun 13 16:21:04 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] File does not exist: /var/www/bias_experiment/surveythree, referer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209181/what-should-be-the-url-of-my-django-application/24209864?noredirect=1
[Fri Jun 13 16:22:36 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant PHP_SELF - assumed 'PHP_SELF' in /var/www/bias_experiment/brendy.php on line 24, referer: http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/
[Fri Jun 13 16:22:36 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: brendy in /var/www/bias_experiment/brendy.php on line 27, referer: http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/
[Fri Jun 13 16:22:36 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant action - assumed 'action' in /var/www/bias_experiment/brendy.php on line 72, referer: http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/
[Fri Jun 13 16:22:36 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: action in /var/www/bias_experiment/brendy.php on line 72, referer: http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/
[Fri Jun 13 16:22:36 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] PHP Warning:  include(footer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/bias_experiment/brendy.php on line 118, referer: http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/
[Fri Jun 13 16:22:36 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'footer.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/bias_experiment/brendy.php on line 118, referer: http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/
[Fri Jun 13 16:22:37 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] File does not exist: /var/www/bias_experiment/special.css, referer: http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/brendy.php
[Fri Jun 13 16:22:37 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] File does not exist: /var/www/bias_experiment/images, referer: http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/brendy.php
[Fri Jun 13 16:22:37 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] File does not exist: /var/www/bias_experiment/images, referer: http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/brendy.php
root@kdeg-vm-18:/var/www/bias_experiment/src#
```

Comment: Do you have access to the Apache error log? It would be useful to know what that says. Also what exactly do you see at the non-working URLs?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I see a "404 Not Found" error page with "Not Found The requested URL /bias_experiment/surveythree/ was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 134.226.38.147 Port 80" No I do not have access to the error logs

Comment: I should see the first page of a very simple user survey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL should be http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/surveythree/

I think there is one tiny error in the Apache configuration, which might be my fault (sorry): you need a trailing slash, so:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /bias_experiment/ /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgi
```

Also note that you don't need to run manage.py runserver, that's pointless as Apache is serving your app.

Comment: No need to apologise for giving em your time. I made that change. No joy unfortunately. I also restarted the server.

Comment: When you say you retstart the server, exactly what command are you running?

Comment: sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Hmm. If you can run sudo, you should be able to see the Apache logs in /var/log/apache2: try doing `sudo su` then `tail /var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: Another thought: have you done `a2ensite bias_experiment` or copied/symlinked your Apache site from sites-available to sites-enabled?

Comment: Error logs added to the original question. Sorry I did not know I could get them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55587/discussion-between-daniel-roseman-and-deepend).

Answer (score 0):

Is this it in your /static/ folder?

http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/static/

Comment: It is but it is not my application but rather just a twitter bootstrap front end I will be adding later.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this changes:

Apache conf:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
ServerName phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie
WSGIScriptAlias /bias_experiment/ /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgi
WSGIDaemonProcess bias_experiment processes=4 threads=25 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup bias_experiment
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

And you need to restart the Apache server.

Comment: Why I get -1 If my answer is the same that has been validated as best? And with more options :s