# Django application hosted on Ubuntu VM with Apache and mod_wsgi not showing up

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

I have uploaded my first Django Application but I am having trouble accessing it. The application is called **survey** and has been uploaded onto an `Ubunto VM` running `Apache` with `mod_wsgi`. My VM has been made public using a Proxy pass at http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment

Per the `urls.py` file below, the survey should be available at http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/surveythree/ When I access it locally it works at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/surveythree/`

I have posted two questions related [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209181/what-should-be-the-url-of-my-django-application)[(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188604/django-application-not-visable) to this lately and have received lots of help on related issues. However the application is still not visible and I do not understand why.

**The steps I took**

- Uploaded the project to /var/www/ (project structure is below)
- Installed virtualenv
- Installed mod_wsgi
- Installed any other related packages
- Created the virtualhost file (below)
- Created the index.wsgi file (below)
- Restarted apache
- Ran a2ensite `a2ensite bias_experiment`
- Restarted apache

However when the user visited http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/surveythree/ they would get an Apache 404 error page and visiting http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/ would show them the file system,

I then added a direct link to the wsgi file by adding the below to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

```
WSGIScriptAlias /bias_experiment/ /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgi
```

Now when the user visits http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/ they at least see Django is running. However visiting http://phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment/surveythree/ still results in an Apache 404 error page.

Can anyone see what is wrong with my setup? I have followed multiple tutorials and extensively looked into this but cannot figure it out.

**The below is my setup** Please feel free to request any aditional details.

Thanks

**My VirtualHost file located at** /etc/apache2/sites-available/bias_experiment

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
ServerName phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie/bias_experiment
ServerAlias phaedrus.scss.tcd.ie
WSGIScriptAlias /bias_experiment/ /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgi

Alias /static/ /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/static/
<Location "/static/">
    Options -Indexes
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

**My index.wsgi file located at** /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgi

```
import os
import sys
import site

# This was kept in order to add the src folder
sys.path.append('/var/www/bias_experiment/src')
sys.path.append('/var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'bias_experiment.settings'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("/var/www/bias_experiment/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**My urls.py file located at** /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),   
    url(r'^surveythree/$', SurveyWizard.as_view([SurveyForm1, SurveyForm2, SurveyForm3, SurveyForm4, SurveyForm5])),   
)
```

**My Apace error Log** `tail /var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
(bias_experiment)spillab@kdeg-vm-18:/var/www/bias_experiment$ sudo tail /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Sun Jun 15 17:37:26 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgisurveythree
[Sun Jun 15 17:37:50 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgisurveythree
[Sun Jun 15 18:38:11 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgisurveythree
[Sun Jun 15 18:39:53 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgisurveythree
[Sun Jun 15 18:40:00 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgisurveythree
[Sun Jun 15 18:40:01 2014] [error] [client 134.226.38.233] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgisurveythree
(bias_experiment)spillab@kdeg-vm-18:/var/www/bias_experiment$
```

**My Project Structure**

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the virtual host is a non-starter, because the server name you are using is the *main* name of that server. So we can probably delete that altogether, and we need to concentrate on what's in `/sites-available/default`. And I think the only thing wrong there is that we don't need a trailing slash in the alias:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /bias_experiment /var/www/bias_experiment/src/bias_experiment/index.wsgi
```

(I might have previously steered you doubly wrong on that, but this time I found the recommendation in the mod_wsgi documentation directly from the author, Graham Dumpleton.)

Comment: Thank you so much. That works perfectly now, bit of an arduous for a first timer like me, but made much easier with your help and ill have a template for the future. I just have to set the read/write permissions on the DB which I remember from the https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes documentation.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working. For the db, you might want to consider moving to a real rdbms like mysql or postgres rather than messing about with sqlite file permissions.